# ag-grid, provide entire dataset client side with proper paging/filtering/sorting

Tags: angular, datatables, ag-grid

I am using a data source class to provide data to the grid, and within the getRows() function I am calculating the rows to return for the current page. The issue with this is that the filtering/sorting then only applies on the current page. I can't find any way to use the grids build in sorting filtering within the getRows() function to return the correct data by filtering the entire dataset. It seems like this would be a basic feature. Data tables and PrimeNG grid both do this out of the box. Am I missing something or does ag-grid really not support this at all? As it is, it seems that there is no way to use paging along with the grids built in filtering/sorting functions if you want the filtering/sorting to apply to the entire dataset (which is the most popular use case imo)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are showing say 10 rows per page, and only putting 10 rows into the `rowData` attribute of the ag-grid? or are you using the [Pagination](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-pagination/) feature?

Comment: I am using the pagination feature. I am not using rowData at all, I am providing a dataSource with a getRows() function similar to how they are doing it in example #1 on the page you linked. if you look at the getRows() function it take allOfTheData and slices it to get the rows for the current page. My issue is that allOfTheData is always the original collection, so as I page through it the order of operations is wrong. First I am getting the page, then it is sorting/filtering the contents of the paged data set. What I want is for it to sort/filter the entire collection, then page.

Comment: Even the example on the site does not work correctly. Sort it by country, and then start paging through the list. Australia will be on every page. What I want is to sort the entire collection by county, and then page so that eventually I am paging through the b's c's d's and don't see Australia anymore on the later pages.

Comment: It even says in the documentation "You have two options for both sorting and filtering. Either you can allow the grid to do it on a particular page (in-grid) or you do it on the server side across the entire data-set."

But why not third options of in-grid sorting/filtering/paging across entire dataset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not yet, there is an open request on their github page for this [enhancement](https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid/issues/587)

On that page there is a suggested workaround by creating a new sort and filter function for each column. Considering how complicated and specific that can get I created a different workaround using the [Slave/Master](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-master-slave/#gsc.tab=0) feature. Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aw9gxyn6/2/) for demonstration purposes.

How it works is by having a ghost grid that only shows the header. This ghost grid will handle all sorting and filtering inherent in ag-grid, then it will pass the sorted/filtered data to the zombie grid.

Relevant code (doesn't include what it took to set up pagination in the first place):

HTML:

```
<div id="ghostGrid" style="height: 25px" class="ag-fresh"></div>
<div id="zombieGrid" style="height: 500px;" class="ag-fresh"></div>
```

**ghostGrid height needs to be the height of the header (default is 25px)**

CSS:

```
.ag-bl-full-height {
  overflow: unset;
}

.ag-menu {
  top: 23px !important;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

**This CSS is necessary to make the filter menu pop up in the right place** (top property might need to be played with in your application)

JS:

```
var zombieGridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    rowData: null,
    headerHeight:0,
    rowModelType: 'pagination',
    paginationPageSize: 50,
    slaveGrids: [],
};

var ghostGridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    rowData: null,
    enableFilter: true,
    enableSorting: true,
    slaveGrids: [],
    onFilterChanged: updateZombieAfterSortAndFilter,
    onSortChanged: updateZombieAfterSortAndFilter
};

function updateZombieAfterSortAndFilter(){
    sortedAndFilteredData = [];
    ghostGridOptions.api.getModel().rowsToDisplay.forEach(e=>sortedAndFilteredData.push(e.data))
    setRowData(sortedAndFilteredData)
}

ghostGridOptions.slaveGrids.push(zombieGridOptions);
zombieGridOptions.slaveGrids.push(ghostGridOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks for finding that! It definitely answers the question. Seems it isn't possible right now without a pretty ugly workaround. I asked a question over there that I will repeat here in case you might know. In the workaround posted, a custom filter and sort function is being used that doesn't handle all complex cases (greater than, less than, starts with, etc) and has to be created for each grid instance because it is specific to the columns. Is it possible to access the grids internal sorting/filtering logic so as to pass in the entire dataset and receive a flter/sorted set back?

Comment: Possible idea: create a ghostGrid and a zombieGrid, ghostGrid isn't shown at all, but just handles sorting/filtering. zombieGrid is what people see and will pass filters to the ghostGrid. You would need to use the api methods like `getModel(), setQuickFilter(), setSortModel()` Not sure how complicated this will get, I will try to come up with an jsfiddle later. (perhaps the slave/master feature would be useful somehow?)

Comment: That's an interesting idea! So essentially the ghost grid is handed the sort/filter options, and then through the api retrieve the data and use it in the getRows() function of the zombieGrid? Not sure I can visualize exactly how that would work, maybe some timeouts to give the ghostGrid time to do its stuff and then pass the result to zombie? Very interested to see what you come up with!